# Controlar una aplicacion de consola desde una web (WebGUI)

Tags: c#

tengo una aplicacion de consola que quisiera controlar desde una Web, mas conocido como WebGUI, lo que yo quiero es que cuando yo presione un boton en la web, el programa vaya a un void o que muestre un mensaje en pantalla, es posible?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Interesante... Cuando lo investigaste, qué descubriste? Qué has intentado? Qué has leido? Qué palabras buscaste en google? Lo que estás describiendo "hacer click en un botón en el navegador desencadene un proceso en un ejecutable" es básicamente la descripción de un servidor web. Entonces, es posible? **Sí, es posible**

Comment: Bueno, como podria hacerlo? , he visto que se puede hacer con sistemas de logeo , pero el que vi que es KeyAuth , solamente se puede usar la webgui en c++

Comment: Si es por medio de un WebView como ejemplo, lo que yo hago es usar CEF (Chromium Embeded Framework) y comunicar por medio de la consola, enviando objetos por medio de un console.log() en Javascript y recibirlos por elevento OnBrowserConsoleMessage() en C#, deserializarlo y ejecutar acciones. Podrias intentar investigar acerca de eso. Si fuera por un medio externo, como un navegador (Mozilla/Chrome/Opeta/Edge/etc) Creo lo que buscas iria mas relacionado con un websocket.